# ¿Cuál es la diferencia entre usar prototipos y no usarlos en c++?

Tags: c++, c, funciones, prototipos

Tengo una pregunta sobre funciones en c++, he aprendido a hacer funciones utilizando prototipos como en el siguiente código:

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int suma(int, int);

int main(){

    int a = 5, b = 4;

    cout<<"\nLa suma de los numeros "<<a<<" y "<<b<<" es: "<<suma(a,b)<<endl;

    return 0;
}

int suma(int x, int y){
    int resultado;
    resultado = x + y;
    return resultado;
}
```

Pero no sé cuál es la diferencia con el siguiente en el que no utilizo el prototipo de la función "suma":

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int suma(int x, int y){
    int resultado;
    resultado = x + y;
    return resultado;
}

int main(){

    int a = 5, b = 4;

    cout<<"\nLa suma de los numeros "<<a<<" y "<<b<<" es: "<<suma(a,b)<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

He visto que varias personas utilizan las funciones en c++ sin definir el prototipo, no tengo muy claro si existe alguna diferencia entre estas dos formas, pues ambas me funcionan. Además he leido que los prototipos son obligatorios en c++, pero no se utiliza el prototipo en el segundo código. ¿Entonces realmente cuál es la diferencia entre usar o no usar los prototipos en c++ y si en c funcionan igual?

Comment: Cuando empiezes a utilizar multiples archivos en tus programas, los prototipos iran en un header, y las funciones las definiras en un archivo aparte. Entonces te sirven para que el compilador sepa que existen aunque su definicion no este a la mano inmediatamente (Si no lo entiendes ahora lo haras cuando te toque hacerlo, de momento no te preocupes por eso). En programas de un solo archivo, a muchos (yo incluido), les gusta tener el main lo mas arriba posible, y otras funciones menos importantes abajo. Pero es solo una cuestion de estilo.

Answer (score 3):

La única diferencia se da en funciones-no-miembro, es decir, en funciones que no pertenecen a una clase.

En estas funciones-no-miembro, el compilador ha de conocer el prototipo **antes de la primera llamada**:

```
int suma( int x, int y ){ return x + y; }

int main( ) {
    std::cout << "Suma: " << suma( 1, 2 ) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Ok, funciona correctamente. El compilador sabe lo que es `suma( )` y los argumentos que espera **antes** de que la uses en `main( )`. Sin embargo:

```
int main( ) {
    std::cout << "Suma: " << suma( 1, 2 ) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}

int suma( int x, int y ){ return x + y; }
```

> error: ‘suma’ was not declared in this scope

En este caso, el compilador no sabe lo que es `suma` y *protesta*. Aquí, **es obligatorio** usar el prototipo:

```
int suma( int x, int y );

int main( ) {
    std::cout << "Suma: " << suma( 1, 2 ) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}

int suma( int x, int y ){ return x + y; }
```